# ¿"IDE0017" VB La inicialización del objeto se puede simplificar?

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net

Estoy recibiendo esta advertencia (IDE0017 C# - La inicialización del objeto se puede simplificar - DATOS - RGAS.vb - Línea 8). Pero no veo la forma de como simplifircalo. Todo lo que intento me da error. ¿Alguien sabe como simplificarlo? Por favor.

El código es el siguiente:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class RGAS
    Public Shared Function RGAS_Select() As DataTable
        Dim oconex As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.cadena)
        oconex.Open()

        Dim ocomand As New SqlCommand   /* Linea 8 */
        ocomand.Connection = oconex
        ocomand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        ocomand.CommandText = "sa_SELECT_RGAS"

        Dim oidr As IDataReader
        oidr = ocomand.ExecuteReader

        Dim odt As New DataTable
        odt.Load(oidr)

        Return odt

        oconex.Close()

    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Imagino que se refiere a que inicialices el objeto desde el constructor

Comment: Claro.. en c# si.. pero como es que recibis un warning de C# si estas programando en vb.net... es una incognita...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- Si te fijas, la palabra `New` esta subrayado con tres puntos, posicionas el mouse arriba del `New` y se lanza una ventana en ella presionas `Mostrar posibles correcciones`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.- Se abrirá una nueva ventana

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde puedes presionar varias opciones, todas ellas se refieren a la modificación de código a nivel de Documento, proyecto, Solución, etc.

En todas ellas se abre la misma tercera ventana, por ejemplo seleccionas "Documento"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le das a aplicar y se realizan los cambios que te ha informado Visual Studio

```
Dim ocomand As New SqlCommand With {
            .Connection = oconex,
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            .CommandText = "sa_SELECT_RGAS"
        }
```

Comment: Eres un crack! Me funcionó, muchas gracias, que Dios te bendiga.